# plot dates with python

Tags: python, plot

I would like to plot nb_lignes over dateTransmission with pyton, using this dataframe:

```
dateTransmission    taux_fraude     nb_lignes
0   2019-08-02  0.054002    61239
1   2019-03-07  0.009358    177914
```

here is my python code :

```
stats_daily_df_pandas.plot.line(x="dateTransmission", y="nb_lignes")
```

I get a plot in x these values : 2019-01 , 2019-02, 2019-03 ... I guess it is only day and year.

How can I modify in the code to have date in the plot with this format : "2019-03-07" ?

Thnanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

stats_daily_df_pandas.plot(x='dateTransmission', y='nb_lignes')
plt.show()
```

Comment: worked on my machine. the link below might help: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html